# React Hooks Form Reset dont set Select to initial value

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

When clicking Reset, form should go back to initial values, but the Select element goes back to first option available, have used the same method for all other form elements, and they update correctly.

Have made a Codesandbox example of the problem : https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-snowflake-tf5te

```
function App() {
  // Data for select dropdown box - selected is Lime
  const SelectData = ["Grapefruit", "Lime", "Coconut", "Mango"];

  // Selected Value
  const selectedValue = "Lime";

  // Set state
  const [selectBox, setSelectBox] = useState(selectedValue);

  // Submit finction
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(`Select Selection #1: ${selectBox}`);
  };

  // Reset function
  const handleReset = () => {
    setSelectBox(selectedValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>
        When 'Reset' is clicked first options is selected
        <br />
        and not the state value.
      </h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Select
          label="Select Fruit"
          value={selectBox}
          handleChange={e => setSelectBox(e.target.value)}
          data={SelectData}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick={handleReset} />
      </form>
      <br />
      Selectbox state value: {selectBox}
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Expected result, after Resetting Form, is that then Select element value is "Lime", but it is "Grapefruit".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed the `value` to `defaultValue` in your `DropDown.js` file and it worked like charm. [Check the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bash-swh5y)

```
<select defaultValue={value} onChange={handleChange}>
            {data.map(item => (
              <option key={item} value={item}>
                {item}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
```

Comment: Mee too. Apparently `defaultValue` is supposed to be used with uncontrolled components. But this one is controlled. https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: See that `value` is supposed to work in this case. But something else is happening. https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-elbakyan-w4ijq

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, work as intended with defaultValue

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Your "bug" is due to the `<input type='reset'/>`.

Change it to a regular button and you'll see that it works just fine.

`<button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-cdn-qchu5

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset

> elements of type "reset"  are rendered as buttons, with a default click event handler that **resets all of the inputs in the form to their initial values.**

This is concurring with your controlled component.

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>
        When 'Reset' is clicked first options is selected
        <br />
        and not the state value.
      </h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Select
          label="Select Fruit"
          value={selectBox}
          handleChange={e => setSelectBox(e.target.value)}
          data={SelectData}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        {/* <input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick={handleReset} /> */}
        <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
      </form>
      <br />
      Selectbox state value: {selectBox}
      <br />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `select` is a controlled component, [`Form` doesn't support `onReset` event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#form-events). Thus, the behavior is similar to `$form.reset()` which will reset the `select` value to default value when `button` of `type=Reset` is clicked.

So an alternative is to use `defaultValue` prop in `select` or use a normal button with `onChange` prop.